# How can one use jk to escape universally without causing hang?

Tags: key-bindings, escape

Recently I was reading http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com, and he said a very fast way to improve your speed in vim is to do `inoremap jk <esc>`. Sure, that made sense.

Then when I next starting using Visual mode, I noticed jk did not work. Sure, yeah, that makes sense. So I added `vnoremap jk <esc>` also.

Next I realized that I needed to use `<esc>` in normal mode too. This is useful when you want to cancel a command, say you accidentally typed in a huge number, and were going to press `dd` when you caught yourself. To get rid of the count, you need to do `<esc>` in Normal mode as well.

So I basically just removed everything else and put `noremap jk <esc>`. But obviously I can no longer smoothly use `j` to scroll down in vim since it is waiting to see (hanging) if I enter `k`.

If I can't use `jk` in all my modes then there's no point in doing this mapping.

So: Is there any way to universally and efficiently use something like `jk` to escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination `jk` is not thought as a general replacement for `<esc>` in all modes. It's just for insert mode to save you from moving your finger up to the `<esc>` key. In all other modes you have to use "normal" `<esc>`, but then `jk` just moves the cursor down and up -- so nothing happens.

There are users out there who redefine their keyboard layout and define the`<CapsLock>` key as `<esc>`. Then you can type `<esc>` with the litte finger of your left hand. (My typing with that finger is so imprecisely, that I often hit `<CapsLock>` when I want to hit `<Shift>`, so I redefined `<CapsLock>` as `<Shift>`.)

I have a lot of customization, but I did not do any special mapping for the essential movement/editing/... keys. That way I have less problems when I work on a Vi/Vim without my setup.

Comment: Nice thing about having `jk` defined in insert mode is that when you're not in insert mode and use the cursor just goes down and back up and you've done nothing and gone nowhere.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Good Point will Update later

Comment: Just to add on, for years I had shortcuts to a couple of essential combinations (save, quit, window movement, `jk` escape, etc)—every once in a while, I would have to go somewhere without my setup. It was painful: I disabled all but the save and quit shortcuts, as those never caused issues (only minor hiccups). I rarely go places without my files, but it happens.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble But just to be clear, you only used `jk` in insert mode, and not visual mode and normal mode, where you used `Esc` instead (disregarding your other mappings). This seems very inconvenient to map two things for `esc`

Comment: @herophant oh it is—but yes, I only used `jk` in insert mode until ditching. Now I just hit escape all the time. More convenient, better muscle memory. My issues now come from mapping CapsLock to Control at a system level, so I cannot hit control keys on any one else's keyboard! Anyway, I see people doing this `jk` thing everywhere. I'm not against it, per se, but I grew tired of the mental divide.

Comment: Weirdly, I never seem to see anyone mention `<C-[>` as an alternative to `<Esc>`, despite the [docs recommending it](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_%3CEsc%3E): *Note: If your `<Esc>` key is hard to hit on your keyboard, train yourself to use `CTRL-[`.* In addition to not requiring any special mappings to use in Vim, `<C-[>` should also generally be portable across unixy terminals and subsequently, other command line programs running within those terminals.